# filter search results with another form

Tags: php, search, form-processing

so here's the problem

I have one form, it outputs search results after submit, with this URL

```
http://localhost/thi/search/results?keyword=barma&search=1&minprice=nomin&maxprice=nomax&minroom=nomin&maxroom=nomax&minyear=nomin&maxyear=2010
```

Now I have another form, which is supposed to filter the results from the previous form by getting the current url of the search results and appending to it the GET variables submitted by this form.

I tried filtering before, but that is with anchor links. How am I supposed to do it with forms? Anny approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just populate the form with the existing data. If it is something that can be changed, then use a text input, a select, or whatever and set the default value to whatever is in the URL. If it can't be changed, use a hidden input.